# Saving multiple files with same name

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, unique, filenames

I'm working on a C# WPF application that does some data processing and outputs files in `.csv` format. What I am trying to achieve is that every time my program runs, it produces a `test.csv` output file, however when I run again with new data.. the new resultant file overwrites the old one. So I am trying to do something so that each created filename is unique. For example, `test.csv`, then `test1.csv`, `test2.csv` and so forth. I came up with the snippet below but I don't think the logic is correct and I can't figure out how to do this. Any help will be appreciated!

```
filename = "C:\\test.csv";
if (File.Exists(filename))
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {    
        filename = "C:\\test" + count + ".csv";
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `std::to_string(count)`.

Comment: You also nred to check `if (File.Exists(filename))` after ever loop in your for loop.  Once that is false then you need to break out of the loop.

Comment: Why not creating a `new Guid` for every file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your original code, you do the check only once. Try (note the `while`):

```
filename = "C:\\test.csv";
int count = 0;

while (File.Exists(filename))
{
    count++;
    filename = "C:\\test" + count + ".csv";                            
}

//save file goes here
```

If you prefer, you can replace the `while` with this `for` loop:

```
for(int count = 0; File.Exists(filename); count++)
    filename = "C:\\test" + count + ".csv";
```

**Update:** As *@eFloh* indicated (see comments), there might be an issue when two instances of the above code are working simultaneously.

This is because there's a slight window between the loop and the actual write-to-disk operation, so other process might just get in the middle and write a file with the same name, overwriting the file the other program is creating or causing errors.

One possible solution is to write a special file to the directory when the loop is executing (and halt the execution is such file exists) to ensure no two running instances will conflict.

Essentially, this file will signal the program that another program is executing this loop - so the other program shall wait until the other terminates.

**Explanation of the code below:** The `using` block is *trying* to create a file called `lock_file` in the directory.

- The `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` makes it possible to both open the file (if already exists) or create it (if it does not).
- The `FileAccess.Write` make is possible to write the `lock_file`
- The `FileShare.Read` makes the using wait until the fine is ***closed*** by other processes - so the program will wait when needed.
- Finally, `FileOptions.DeleteOnClose`, makes the `using` block delete the `lock_file` on exit. This is extremely important because otherwise, the `lock_file` will stay there forever, rendering this block to wait forever to the deletion of this file.

To wrap up (again, credit for this piece goes to *@eFloh*):

```
using(new FileStream("C:\\lock_file", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read, 4096, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose))
{
    //loop and saving goes here
}
```

Comment: initialize the count before the while and get rid of the for loop and you're good to go

Comment: Change `while` into `for` and put `int count = 0` as well as `count++` into it

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Why? There's no added benefit to that except to decrease the number of lines of code. It also appears (at least to me) a bit less readable than the `while` loop. Personally, I would choose the `while` loop over either of the other options presented.

Comment: The `while` is more readable to my taste. Nevertheless I added the `for` solution as well.

Comment: This solutions has a race condition between checking if the file exists and actually creating it.

Comment: How is this a race condition? Assuming that the number of files matching the naming pattern of `test#.csv` is finite (which is always is, and no other process is creating files in the same time), the program will always terminate successfully. Obviously if you're dealing with a vast amount of files (so you worry about the time it takes for the loop to terminate), you can set a maximum number of iterations and generate a `GUID` (as suggested at other answers) or something else. You can also start at the max (like `test10000.csv`) and work your way down, ensuring minimal execution time.

Comment: just consider the program runs twice at the same time. Then this can happen: You exit the `while(File.Exists)`-loop in Instance A and B on the same number. Instance A then creates the file and Instance B tries to write or overrides the existing file, depending on A having the file still open or not.

Comment: see my answer below to mitigate that situation. But using a Lockfile is fine, too. in that case I recommend a using(new FileStream(lockFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read, 8 * 1024, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose)) {...} block. This will automagically delete your lockfile when the block is exited.

Answer (score 2):

you can check until you find available file name with LINQ

```
var pathFormat = "c:\\test{0}.csv";

var maxIndex = Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue)
    .SkipWhile(x => File.Exists(string.Format(pathFormat, x)))
    .First();

var csvPath = string.Format(pathFormat, maxIndex);
Console.WriteLine(csvPath);
```

Comment: This is a bit overkill for the purpose (and really doesn't require LINQ). A simple `for` or `while` loop will suffice.

Comment: I know, just want to show different options. @EBrown

Comment: Hence why I didn't say this is a *bad answer*. It's not. It's just a bit larger (and less readable, though that is an opinion) than a `while` or `for` solution.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can apply a different file naming convention, like for example: [file name]+timestamp to ensure its uniqueness, thus there will be no need for the duplicate name check:

```
    DateTime _dt = DateTime.Now;
    string filename = @"C:\test_" + 
        _dt.Year.ToString() +
        _dt.Month.ToString() + 
        _dt.Month.ToString() + 
        _dt.Day.ToString() + "_" +
        _dt.Hour.ToString()+
        _dt.Minute.ToString()+
        _dt.Second.ToString() +".csv";
}
```

Upon necessity, you can extend it by adding  `_dt.Millisecond.ToString()`.Or, instead of using the timestamp you can add GUID to the file name to ensure its uniqueness.

Hope this may help.

Answer (score 1):

Because whenever you check and *then* try to write, you may have someone having created another file in the meantime, you should try-open in a loop to escape the race condition:

```
            int tryCount = 1;
            string pathFormat = "c:\\test{0}.csv";

            while (tryCount <= MAX_TRYCOUNT)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, pathFormat, tryCount), FileMode.CreateNew))
                    {
                        //fs.Write or open StreamWriter etc.
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {
                    /* try next filename */
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    /* other unexpected error, escape. */
                    throw;
                }

                tryCount++;
            }

            if (tryCount == MAX_TRYCOUNT)
            {
                throw new IOException("No free filename available.");
            }
```

an alternative approach would be to lock all your applications (or application instances) writing at the same time:

```
string lockFile = Path.Combine(PATH_OF_EXPORTDIR,"SingleInstanceCanWrite");
using(new FileStream(lockFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read, 8 * 1024, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose))
{
   /* find next free filename, open write and close */
}
```

but this only moves the race condition towards correctly checking the lockfile, you will need a try-catch here, too. :)